# Sending Windows Form through TCP

Tags: c#, winforms, serialization, tcp

I am developing an application whose main features are:

- A group of friends want to have a game of remote role-playing.
- The GM opens the application and starts a server. It opens a winForm.
- Clients do the same and connect to the server. The list of connected players is updated on all windows (clients / server)
- The GM opens a window on his screen and this is also displayed on all clients.
  When he draws on it, the drawing also displays "live" on all client screens.

So far I manage to do everything described above except for the last step: drawing on a panel on the server side does not send the drawing to the clients.

To achieve displaying the opened windows on the client side, I serialized my winforms via a custom class. Here is a portion of code to serialize / deserialize :

```
public static String Serialise(Control c)
{
    XmlTextWriter xmlSerialisedForm = new XmlTextWriter(Application.StartupPath + @"\serialise.xml", System.Text.Encoding.Default);
    xmlSerialisedForm.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    xmlSerialisedForm.WriteStartDocument();
    xmlSerialisedForm.WriteStartElement("ChildForm");
    // enumerate all controls on the form, and serialise them as appropriate
    AddChildControls(xmlSerialisedForm, c);
    xmlSerialisedForm.WriteEndElement(); // ChildForm
    xmlSerialisedForm.WriteEndDocument();
    xmlSerialisedForm.Flush();
    xmlSerialisedForm.Close();
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.Load(Application.StartupPath + @"\serialise.xml");
    return xmlDoc.InnerXml;
}

public static void Deserialise(Control c, string XmlFileName) {
    XmlDocument xmlSerialisedForm = new XmlDocument();
    xmlSerialisedForm.LoadXml(XmlFileName);
    XmlNode topLevel = xmlSerialisedForm.ChildNodes[1];
    foreach (XmlNode n in topLevel.ChildNodes) {
      SetControlProperties((Control)c, n);
    }
}
```

I have read dozen of web articles here and there about NOT deserializing Windows Form BUT is there another way to achieve what I'm aiming ?

How can I send through TCP connection to the connected clients data about what i'm doing live on my screen ?

I'm actually building this app to know more about TCP connections and C# in general and my goal is to reproduce what this software, written in C with QT, is actually doing.

[Rolistik site](http://rolistik.free.fr/copiesdecran.html)

[Rolistik sources](http://rolistik.free.fr/telechargement/Rolistik%201.1%20-%20sources.zip)

Screenshot of a server and a client with a winform launched by the server and received by the client
[image: Screenshot of a server and a client with a winform launched by the server and received by the client]

Thanks for the incoming help

Leor

Comment: If all that changes is the drawing, why not send the instructions for drawing instead of the entire form?

Comment: I would like, that seems to be a good idea, I don't know how to do it.
Before thinking to use serialisation, i wanted to send to clients, infos on how to construct the windows forms but I didn't knew how to do it. Any more information on this to give ?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/371955/Motion-JPEG-Streaming-Server) can be of interest